# Search results for checked out documents to a user, inside a document set

Tags: search, search-results, document-set, check-out

If I perform the following search (replacing [domain] and [username] with appropriate values):

/search/pages/results.aspx?k=CheckoutUserOWSUSER%3A[domain]%5C[username]

It returns search results listing all checked out documents for that user... **unless documents are in a document set**. If that user has 5 checked out documents inside a document set, it only returns the latest changed document from that set (1 document), and ignores the other 4.

Draft item security has been set to "Any user who can read items" for the document set library. I have also tried publishing all items to ensure there's at least 1 major version, then checking them out, with same results.

Does anyone know how to get the correct number of results showing for checked out documents inside document sets?